# Vb.Net how to add another query to table?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio

Initially, I had one query that I converted it to PDF report (tables). However, now I would like to add another query in the table.
So that I have one query in a column.

My report have 3 columns and this query should be in third column as the first query will return two values id and name.
The second query I did was about calculating something.

Currently my code is like this:

```
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader

            command.CommandText = query
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.Connection = con
            con.Open()

        dr = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim counter = 0
        While dr.Read
            Dim row As Row = table.AddRow()
            row.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center

            If counter Mod 2 = 0 Then
                row.Shading.Color = TableRowA
            Else
                row.Shading.Color = TableRowB
            End If
            counter += 1

            row.Cells(0).AddParagraph(counter)
            row.Cells(0).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
            row.Cells(0).VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom
            row.Cells(1).AddParagraph(dr.GetString(1))
            row.Cells(1).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
            row.Cells(2).AddParagraph(dr.GetInt32(0))
            row.Cells(2).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
            row.Cells(3).AddParagraph("")
            row.Cells(3).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
        End While
```

Can you show me how to alter this code to add the other query I have in last column?

Do I have to do While loop again? do I have to have another dr?

What I did is:

```
                Dim drquery2 As SqlDataReader

                Dim dr As SqlDataReader

            command.CommandText = query
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.Connection = con
            con.Open()

        dr = command.ExecuteReader()


            command.CommandText = query2
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.Connection = con
            con.Open()

        drquery2 = command.ExecuteReader()


        Dim counter = 0
        While dr.Read
            Dim row As Row = table.AddRow()
            row.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center

            If counter Mod 2 = 0 Then
                row.Shading.Color = TableRowA
            Else
                row.Shading.Color = TableRowB
            End If
            counter += 1

            row.Cells(0).AddParagraph(counter)
            row.Cells(0).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
            row.Cells(0).VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom
            row.Cells(1).AddParagraph(dr.GetString(1))
            row.Cells(1).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
            row.Cells(2).AddParagraph(dr.GetInt32(0))
            row.Cells(2).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
            row.Cells(3).AddParagraph(drquery2.GetInt32(0))
            row.Cells(3).Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left
        End While
```

Is it correct?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean.  Can you elaborate?  Specifically, what have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Yes this is pretty unclear. Are you trying to use the results of query 1 as inputs for query 2? Or are you trying to insert the data from query 1 into a table to present to the user? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to add another query to my report table

Comment: do everything in a single query at the database level or store the results of your first query in a datatable then process the datatable to obtain the values of your third column from code

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a `Do...Until` loop instead of `While`? Then try to use the counter as a `Do Until counter = 3` (or maybe 4. It's been a while since I've done anything like this)